# Not able to add Sharepoint Framework webpart on page under a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I created and deployed a SharePoint framework WebPart in the app catalog.
Then I added the WebPart in a page of the top level of a site collection.
Its working fine in top level site collection pages.
But I am not able to add the same WebPart in a page which is under a subsite not top level site collection.
Tried adding the app in subsite but showing the error saying that app already added. But I have added the app only in the top level of a site collection, not in the subsite.

Please help me on this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you using a feature? Which scope?

Comment: I have no idea about feature related to this and scoping. I just deployed the app to the app catalog and then added the app in root site collection. and I was able to see the WebParts for the root site collection pages but not for the sub site pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the app in root site and deleted it from recycle bin, and then I was able to add the app again into root site and also in the subsite. And web part came in the both the places.

looks weird, not sure why it happened like this.